# many retains placed on NSURL when using arrayWithContentsOfURL

Tags: iphone, nsarray, retain

I am creating an NSArray from a URL that points to a plist

```
NSLog(@"_url rc:[%d]",[_url retainCount]); //prints "_url rc:[1]"
content = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:_url];
NSLog(@"_url rc:[%d]",[_url retainCount]); //prints "_url rc:[10]"
```

I'm completely at a loss as to why this is occurring.  Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: What's the problem? As long as you're taking care of your own retains and releases, the framework will do the same.

Comment: Most probably the framework is doing a retain for each item in the array since it keeps a pointer to the actual value. or something... does the retain count on the url come down to 1 if you release properly the array? if yes, nothing to worry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Do not call -retainCount.

The absolute retain count of an object is useless *unless your code is the only thing that has ever touched the object*.  As soon as you pass the object through system API's the absolute retain count is no longer something you have any control over.

As *chrissr* implied, the retain count of an object should be treated entirely as a delta.  If you cause it to be increased, you should cause it to be decreased.   If you retain, you must release.  If you copy, you must release.  Etc...

Comment: I appreciate the help, I was just curious as to why it shot to 10.

Comment: because the framework wants to ensure the `NSURL` object stays around even if you release it. :-)

Comment: If I were to guess, `arrayWithContentsOfURL:` is doing some kind of recursive parse of the document and the `_url` is being retained/autoreleased possibly by a caching mechanism and problem a few times as the parse occurs (as DTDs are read and the like).